# How can I create an associative array from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is what I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedId[{{ order.id }}]">

const orders = [];
$("input[type=checkbox][name*='selectedId']:checked").each(function (index) {
    let id          = $(this).attr('name').match(/[-0-9]+/);
    orders[index]   = id[0];
});
```

And I get:

```
orders = [0 => 1, 1 => 2]
```

What I would like to get is:

```
orders = [
    0 => ["id" => 1],
    1 => ["id" => 2]
];
```

> orders[index]["id"] = id[0] doesn't work

Comment: `orders[index] = { id: id[0] };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has objects, not associative arrays. For your desired result, you'd want something like this:

```
let orders = [];
$("input[type=checkbox][name*='selectedId']:checked").each(function (index) {
    orders[index] = { id: $(this).attr('name').match(/[-0-9]+/)[0] };
});
```

or you could also use [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
orders.push({ id: $(this).attr('name').match(/[-0-9]+/)[0] });
```

Also, [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is meant for non-mutable constants, so you may want to use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead.